# MySQL join 2 columns with int type and varchar type

Tags: mysql, join, types

I need make query on two tables and the columns are diffrent type. And I can't adjust the tables. 
It is posible?

That is query whitsch don't work:

```
$query = "SELECT table1.column_content
          FROM table1 OUTER JOIN table2 ON table1.int_column = table2.varcharcolumn
          WHERE (((table2.uid)=$uid))";
```

I need something like this:

```
$query = "SELECT table1.column_content
          FROM table1 OUTER JOIN table2 ON CONVERT(table1.int_column, VARCHAR) = table2.varcharcolumn
          WHERE (((table2.uid)=$uid))";
```

Thank you TB

Comment: So what's your question? Seems like you already posted a solution.

Comment: It works without convert() too :). So thanks
TB

Comment: Maybe is there some subtleties involved? In that case you should explain it, and provide some actual data sample... Otherwise, please post yourself an *answer* and accept it in order to "close" this question.

Comment: What kind of OUTER JOIN is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works without convert() too :). So thanks

I put just this:

```
$query = "SELECT table1.column_content
          FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.int_column = table2.varcharcolumn
          WHERE (((table2.uid)=$uid))"
```

and it works. There were another problem.

TB